# RSS Feed not scrolling or opening browser?

Tags: android, rss

I have two working rss feeds. Both update like expected, however my first rss feed is scrolllable and allows each article to be clicked (browser appears then). Im just wondering if im missing something important to do this or im doing it wrong??

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    try {
                        URL rssUrl1 = new URL("http://rss");
                        SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                        SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                        XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                        RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                        myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                        InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl1.openStream());
                        myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
                        myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed(); 



                        ///URL rssUrl1 = new URL("http://rss");
                        URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.midlandsireland.ie/news.rss");
                        SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory1 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                        SAXParser mySAXParser1 = mySAXParserFactory1.newSAXParser();
                        XMLReader myXMLReader1 = mySAXParser1.getXMLReader();
                        RSSHandler myRSSHandler1 = new RSSHandler();
                        myXMLReader1.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler1);
                        InputSource myInputSource1 = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                        myXMLReader1.parse(myInputSource1);
                        myRssFeed1 = myRSSHandler1.getFeed(); 

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();    
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();    
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();    
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    if (myRssFeed!=null && myRssFeed1!=null) {
                        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter =
                                new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(), 
                                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myRssFeed.getList());
                                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter1 =
                               new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(),            
                                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRssFeed1.getList());
                        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(),            
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<RSSItem>()));

                     ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapterEmpty1 = 
                               new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(),            
                                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<RSSItem>());
                        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapterEmpty1);
                    } 
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                }
            }
            @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {     
                Uri feedUri = Uri.parse(myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, feedUri);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        }
```

Ive tried adding working feed to the second feeds position, so i think its something to do with listview or textview? what do you guys think?

---

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    if (myRssFeed!=null && myRssFeed1!=null) {
                        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter =
                                new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(), 
                                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myRssFeed.getList());
                                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter1 =
                               new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(),            
                                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRssFeed1.getList());
                                            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
                                                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
                                                lv.setOnItemClickListener(mListener);   


                                                ListView lv.OnItemClickListener mListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                        Uri feedUri1 = Uri.parse(myRssFeed1.getItem(position).getLink());
                                                        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, feedUri1);
                                                        startActivity(myIntent1);                   
                                                    };
                                                }





                    }
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="ClickTourismButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:text="Touism Guide" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Whats Nearby" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Favouites" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"  
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="See Full Map" />   

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp" /> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
         />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your second feed doesn't work?

Comment: it works, it updates and displays new articles. However it doesnt allow me to scroll or click on the articles like my previous rss feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListActivity` which you seem to use, manages a single `ListView` widget. Following this, the `onListItemClick` callback that you use in the `Activity` will work only for the `ListView` managed by the `ListActivity`(the one with the id `android.R.id.list`). For the other `ListView` you'll need to set your own `OnItemClickeListener`. For example:

```
// a field in your ListActivity
OnItemClickListener mListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         // do the stuff for the second list feed                   
    }
}
```

Set this `OnItemClickListener` on your second `ListView` to listen for events somewhere in your code(like the `onPostExecute` method):

```
// ...
ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRssFeed1.getList());
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(mListener);
// the rest of the code...
```

Comment: I keep getting errors now, "void is an invalid type for the variable OnItemClickListener" "OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @JosephKenny Please import the `OnItemClickListener` class(CTRL + SHIFT + O in `Eclipse`). Also make sure that `mListener` is a field in the `Activity` (declared right below `public class etc .. {`).

Comment: @JosephKenny You've deleted the previous code, where the errors appearing because of `lv.OnItemClickListener ....`? Also, if you can't scroll the second feed post the layout that you use with the two ListViews.

Comment: Added the field, Added the code. Ive updated the my post above to show you. Im still getting an error thou???

Comment: @JosephKenny My code is pretty clear, please copy it as I wrote it, so don't write `lv.OnItemCLickListener ....` as this is just incorrect. I was asking for the **full** layout containing the two `ListViews`.

Comment: full layout posted above @luksprog

Comment: is that everything you want too see @luksprog??

Comment: @JosephKenny I'm guessing you see the second `ListView`. The problem is the last `TextView` from the layout which covers the second `ListView`. Move it before the second ListView in the xml layout and it should work. Also that layout is awful, you should really read about layouts in general as the graphical editor outputs horrific code.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for being a nuisance. It works just the way i wanted. I had no idea the textview should be ahead of the listview. Thank you